# Whats the best way to implement a filter for this hierarchical structure

Tags: java, filter, hierarchy

I have this hierarchical structure:

```
public class Category {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class SubCategory {

    private String name;
    private Category category;

    public SubCategory(String name, Category category) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Category getCategory(){
        return category
    }
}

public class Event {

    private String name;
    private SubCategory subCategory;
    private Collection<Result> result;

    public Event(String name, SubCategory subCategory,
            Collection<Result> result) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subCategory = subCategory;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public SubCategory getSubCategory() {
        return subCategory;
    }

    public Collection<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

}

public class Result {

    private Integer id;
    private String result;

    public Result(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

I need to implement following method:

```
public Collection<Event> filter(String category, String subcategory, String result);
```

If some of the parameters are null it should return all the possibilities.

What I created (its very stupid but only that is in my head):

```
public Collection<Event> filter(String category, String subcategory, String result) {

Collection<Event> res = new HashSet<Event>();

for (Event event : events) {
    if (event.getSubCategory().getCategory().getName().equals(category)) {
        res.add(event);
    }
    if (event.getSubCategory().getName().equals(subcategory)) {
        res.add(event);
    }

    for (Result result : event.getResult()) {
        if (result.getName().equals(result)
                && event.getSubCategory().getName().equals(subcategory)
                && event.getSubCategory().getCategory().getName().equals(category)) {
            res.add(event);
        }
    }
}

    return res;
}
```

I dont want to use java 8 !
Also the structure is fixed. I cannot change it. I can add methods and classes and change existing methods but not change the structure at all.

Comment: I would recommend using an `enum` rather than a class with a single `String name` field.

Comment: this is just an example. I don't want to change the structure.

Comment: For being an example, it should be done with `enum` rather than with classes. And you can ease all the code by implementing `equals` method on the `Category` class.

Comment: ok now we have no single fields in classes

Comment: May I ask why do you have the category inside the subcategory? Despite that, think you need to make the subcategory a subclass of category and implement the comparable interface in your classes. Then the subcategory class  can override the compareTo method and you can use that into the filter.

Comment: I cannot change the structure. Any other Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Java 8 streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to filter your data:

```
public Collection<Event> filter(String category, String subcategory, String result) {
    Stream<Event> s = events.stream();
    if (category != null) { // filter for category
        s = s.filter(e -> e.getSubCategory().getCategory().equals(category));
    }
    if (subCategory != null) { // filter for sub category
        s = s.filter(e -> e.getSubCategory().equals(subCategory));
    }
    if (result != null) { // filter for result
        s = s.filter(e -> e.getResult()
                           .stream()
                           .anyMatch(r -> getResult().equals(result))
                    );
    }

    return s.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```